How do I sort questions by views?
Suppose I am searching for a question, and there are many similarish questions to that which come on the search. How do I filter out for those questions which have the maximum views?

Apparently you can’t (anymore): https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/113042/196432

You can use views when searching, for example, searching for telescoping sum views:10000 restrigst the results to questions with at least 10000 views.
See also:
Searching questions by number of views,
Using the views feature during searches and
How do I sort the questions by the number of views?

It is also mentioned in the help center and in one of the bullet points here: How to search on this site?
